# How to create relationships (a->b->c)among those nodes by importing csv data

Tags: neo4j, relational-database, csv-import

I have a database of existing nodes and would like to add in additional relationships from a CSV file which looks like this:

```
id_from, id_to,point, nextpoint
1,2,HEILBRONN,ILSFELD
2,3,ILSFELD,MUNDELSHEIM
```

i would like to create a relationship (a->b->c) just like HEILBRONN->ILSFELD->MUNDELSHEIM

How can i get it? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Cypher, assuming the `id_from` and `id_to` in the file are the `id` property of the nodes (and that the property is indexed):

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///path/to/file.csv' AS line
MATCH (from {id: toInt(line.id_from)}), (to {id: toInt(line.id_to)})
MERGE from-[:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE]->to
```